# Add web view 2 times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a question. I want to put 2 webviews in one FlatList and between them I want to put view block. How I can do this? I tried to put flex 1, and it just showed data of the last webview.
Help me please

```html
       <FlatList
       data={this.state.dataSource}
        ItemSeparatorComponent = {this.FlatListItemSeparator}
                renderItem={({item}) =>
                <View style={{flex: 1}}>
          
           <MyWebView style={{flex: 1}} 
               source={{html: `1` }}
           />
           <View>
           // here will be block
           </View>
 
 <MyWebView style={{flex: 1}} 
               source={{html: `2` }}
           />
 
             
            </View>
                }
                keyExtractor={item => item.id}
              />
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `flex:1` for between component or give according to your requirement.

```
  <View style={{flex:1}}>
     <WebView style={{flex:1}}
       source={{`any html code`}}
      />
      <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <Text>{your text}</Text>
       </View>
      <WebView 
        source={{`any html code`}}
       />
   </View>
```

Comment: no, it is not working. It show just the last WebView